# Default value of initalizing arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays

I was confused why my default value for my int array was 1 while I was fixing a function in C. I thought the default value of an array if uninitialized is 0 (or garbage). This caused some frustration because I was using the int array as a check to see if a number was already used for matching one array to the other.

Was pretty confused until I decided to print out the "used" array and found that I had some very large values, some -1s, and a bunch of 1s (I originally used a value of 1 to see if that slot was already used for a previous match and didn't get expected results. I used 12 but this is a hack and I want to understand the best way to do a check against an originally uninitialized array that will then be filled.

Could anyone help me straighten out my understanding of array initialization? When I use "char arr[n] = {0}" it won't compile (so I'm guessing that it's because of c99) but "char arr[n]; " should work? I guess I can use memset(arr, '0', n) to populate it all with '0's but this doesn't seem to work for ints.

```
bool comp(const int *a, const int *b, size_t n) {
        int used[n];
        //memset(used, 0, n);   
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
                int count = 1;
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
                        int powered = pow(a[j], 2);
                        if (powered == b[i] && used[j] != 12 ) {
                                printf(" Matched at %d: %d %d \n", j, powered, b[i]);
                                count++;
                                used[j] = 12;
                                break;
                        }
                }
                /*for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(used) / sizeof(used[0]); i++){
                        printf("Used has %d\n" , used[i]);
                }*/

                if (count == 1) return false;
        }
        return true;
}
```

Comment: @ser6461080 Where is there an array initialized in the presented code?

Comment: "or garbage" is correct as the array is not initialised. So why are you surprised with a value of `1`? Garbage means any value.

Comment: use `memset(arr, 0, n * sizeof(int))`

Comment: `int used[n]` creates a [variable length array (VLA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). You cannot use an initializer with a VLA. So you need to use `memset` or a loop to initialize it. The reason your `memset` didn't work is because you passed the wrong size. Try `memset(used, 0, sizeof(used));` And to see the difference try `printf("%zu %zu\n", n, sizeof(used))`

Comment: Note that in C, `'0' == 30` (assuming ASCII). `memset(arr, '0', sizeof(arr))` does NOT zero an array. Eraklon's comment does.

Comment: Also, when something has a 'garbage' value, you can assume nothing about what might be stored there. Uninitialized variables/arrays do not have a special value of 'garbage' or 'undefined'. They can have whatever happens to be hanging in your memory.

Comment: @HelloWorld — `'0'` is normally 0x30 or 48.

Comment: Thank you everyone. So best practice is to initialize a char array with memset(arr, 0, n * sizeof(int)). Since C treats chars and ints the same do we need to do the same for an int array or is simply declaring "int arr[n]; " enough. @Vlad from Moscow the array is "int used[n]"

Comment: @user6461080 The best way is `memset(arr, 0, sizeof(arr))` for a couple of reasons. The first being that if they type of array changes (e.g. you decide to switch to a `long` array) you don't have to remember to switch the operand of `sizeof` to `long`. This aslo prevents mistakes when you change the size of the array. Say you decide your array needs `n + 1` elements for some implementation detail like a [sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value). Now your `memset()` command is broken. Best to just go with the size, and then you can't mess up :)

Answer (score 2):

The default value of any auto variable in the C is undefined -- it is not initialized to anything unless you do so explicitly.  It doesn't matter if it is an array or not -- either way it is uninitialized.

So you need to initialize the array.  Unfortunately, according to the C99 spec, you can't initalize variable-sized arrays like this, so your only choice is explicitly overwrite the garbage by using `memset` like in your comment, or explicitly assigning to every element.